# JavaScript memory: return new object vs. store in result

Tags: javascript, memory, garbage-collection

I've been wondering about memory usage and garbage collection in JavaScript when returning new (temporary) objects. Say I have a function that returns multiple values:

```js
function foo() {
    return { a: 0, b: 1, c: 2 };
}
```

This creates a new Object every time the function is called. Now, if I'm only interested in the return values, I don't really need that object, so I thought of a different pattern:

```js
function bar(result) {
    result.a = 0;
    result.b = 1;
    result.c = 2;
}
```

In theory, bar should save some memory over foo. In fact I saw this pattern a few times in real world applications, e.g. in three.js there are "optionalTarget" parameters in the Ray class so the functions don't have to create new vectors inside and instead set the result on the target ([Ray.js source](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/math/Ray.js#L56)).

However, after fiddling around with custom benchmarks, I cannot find any differences in practice. I'm a total novice in benchmarking Javascript, so the question is: Can you create a convincing benchmark to show the difference, if any? If there is none, does this mean the garbage collector is smart enough to throw away the object immediately?

Comment: Are you sure you do have a performance problem that would justify making your API more complex ? *Hint : not here*

Comment: I'm developing collision detection, so yes, every little bit helps. Also the three.js example shows that people really do that. If there was no difference, keeping the API simpler would be great!

Comment: Always keep the API simple and do not use any tricks until you see some bottlenecks. And then, only then change the API. If you could not measure any difference, then there might not be any difference in your usecase.

Comment: With modern JS engines, object/function creation is very fast, especially if you always use the same properties names (yes, engines are smart). I'd suggest you to first write your program by focusing on API usability and simplicity and only after to look at optimization, starting by reading a little on how it works (for example http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/v8/).